# Output / echo string without quotation marks

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe, echo

Is there any way I can echo a string without using single or double quotation marks. Here's my issue.

If I have a bash script with the following contents it works as expected.

```
./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e 'console.log("thomas")'
```

I'm trying to use that exact code, I cant alter it in any way. And I'm trying to execute it as a string within one command.

I tried wrapping the string-to-echo in single and double quotes and it doesn't execute right because the code has both single and double quotes.

```
echo './node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e 'console.log("thomas")'' | sh

echo "./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e 'console.log("thomas")'" | sh
```

Is there any way I can execute the code above in one line and pipe it to `sh`?

Comment: @Cyrus I don't want to have to escape the strings. It's valid code when it's on it's own in a file!

Comment: Can't you do `cmd | sh`?

Comment: What is output of `./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e 'console.log("thomas")'`?

Comment: This string can be an entire bash file and should be able to be run as such. @anubhava what does the output matter?

Comment: Can't you just use `./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e 'console.log("thomas")' | bash` then?

Comment: `bash ./your_file` or `source ./your_file`?

Comment: On another note, you could think about using `heredoc`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly easiest to escape the double quotes:

```
echo "./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e 'console.log(\"thomas\")'" | sh
```

Or do:

```
sh << EOF
./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e 'console.log("thomas")'
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could piece together a string variable from a couple of pieces:

```
a='./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e '
b='console.log("thomas")'
c=$a"'"$b"'"
echo $c | sh
```

EDIT: Oops, I missed the "in one line" part. I don't know why you want that, but I guess you can string it all together on one line:

```
a='./node_modules/.bin/json -I -f ./test.json -e '; b='console.log("thomas")'; c=$a"'"$b"'"; echo $c | sh
```

(and if you want it a little shorter, you could do `echo $a"'"$b"'"` and never define `c`.)